# Reading in a 2d array and displaying it (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, for-loop, multidimensional-array

So the premise of my code is to read in a 2d array from a .txt. The array is a game board but the first two lines are what determine the size of the board. After i read it in i want it to find wherever the character "U" is, and then display the array but only showing U and whats around it. Problem is i cant get the array to print the right size and the code for displaying the U is not working either.

```
ifstream inputFile;
int boardSizeRow;
int boardSizeCol;
inputFile.open("C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\fileboard2.txt");
inputFile >> boardSizeRow;
inputFile >> boardSizeCol;
inputFile.get();


char gameBoard[20][20];
for (int row = 0; row < boardSizeRow; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < boardSizeCol; col++)
    {
        gameBoard[row][col] = inputFile.get();
    }
}


for (int row = 0; row < boardSizeRow; row++) //////////////TO TEST PRINT
{
    for (int col = 0; col < boardSizeCol; col++)
    {
        cout << gameBoard[row][col];
    }
}

cout << endl;
cout << endl;

const int ROWS = 20; 
const int COLS = 20;
bool toPrint[ROWS][COLS] = {false}; 
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ )
{
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
    {
       if (gameBoard[i][j] == 'U')
       {
            //set parameters around:
            toPrint[i][j] = true; 
            toPrint[i][j-1] = true; //West
            toPrint[i][j+1] = true; //East
            toPrint[i-1][j] = true;  //North
            toPrint[i+1][j] = true; //South
       }
   }
}
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ )
{
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
    {
       if (toPrint[i][j])
       {            
           cout << gameBoard[i][j] ;
       }
       else
       {
           cout <<"0";
       }
    }
    cout <<endl;
 }
cout << endl; 

return 0;
```

. txt FILE::

```
20
20
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
  W GO  W          W
W WW      w    S   W
W H W   GW  w      W
WPW  WW          G W
 WK       W        W
W W W  W    w   w  W
  WK WU            W
    SW      w  w   W
           W       W
    w    W       G W
  G    W       w   W
D   wwwww          W
         K   w  D  W
w w   W w   w      W
    ww  w    WWWWWWW
  G        w       W
    ww  w S    w   W
   WWW      G      W
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Comment: What output do you get? Could you edit the question and add that to it?

Answer (score 0):

You forget to read the new line symbol in txt. If you look at the gameBoard array, you will find the first item on 2nd row is 10' '.

modified code:

```
for (int row = 0; row < boardSizeRow; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < boardSizeCol; col++)
    {
        gameBoard[row][col] = inputFile.get();
    }
    inputFile.get();//read new line symbol here
}


for (int row = 0; row < boardSizeRow; row++) 
{
    for (int col = 0; col < boardSizeCol; col++)
    {
        cout << gameBoard[row][col];
    }
    cout<<endl;//output new line here
}
```

Comment: so what changes do i need to make?